# Flexbox row not displaying div's side by side

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

My Flexbox is not displaying two divs as columns but one underneth the other. Not sure why as I have `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`.

App.js file:

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="innerBox">
        <div className="innerBoxContent">
          <div className="menu">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <h1>content</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CSS file:

```
.App {
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 35);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.innerBox{
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;

  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
}

.menu{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
}

.content
{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Picture:
[image: Flex-box Displaying rows as columns]

Can someone explain why its not working as intended. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

""
Should be removed as the flex-box is being applied to it and not its contents

Fix for HTML file should look like this

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="innerBox">       
          <div className="menu">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <h1>content</h1>
          </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.App {
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 35);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.innerBox{
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;

  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
}

.menu{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
    text-align: center;

}

.content
{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}


/* add This Class*/
.innerBoxContent{
    display:flex;
    aling-item:center;
    justify-content:center;
    
}




import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="innerBox">
        <div className="innerBoxContent">
          <div className="menu">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <h1>content</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS property `flex-wrap: nowrap;` should be added to container with class name `.innerBox`.

```
.innerBox{
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;

  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `menu` and `content` components are inside of `.innerContent` block.
So `.innerBoxContent` should be flex.

```css
.innerBoxContent {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```